# C compiling errors on debian

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, debian, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile a C program, ipad_charge (https://github.com/mkorenkov/ipad_charge), on Debian (Raspberry Pi Raspbian).  It was written for Ubuntu and I have no trouble installing it there.  On Debian, I get compiling errors;

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra ipad_charge.c -lusb-1.0 -o ipad_charge
ipad_charge.c: In function ‘set_charging_mode’:
ipad_charge.c:37:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘libusb_strerror’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
ipad_charge.c:37:3: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
ipad_charge.c:43:3: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
ipad_charge.c:53:3: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
ipad_charge.c: In function ‘main’:
ipad_charge.c:152:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
/tmp/cc1hdopk.o: In function `set_charging_mode':
ipad_charge.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `libusb_strerror'
ipad_charge.c:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `libusb_strerror'
ipad_charge.c:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `libusb_strerror'
/tmp/cc1hdopk.o: In function `main':
ipad_charge.c:(.text+0x5fc): undefined reference to `libusb_strerror'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'ipad_charge' failed
make: *** [ipad_charge] Error 1
```

When I look at the code, it seems like libusb is doing the heavy lifting.  My guess is that I need to run a more current version of libusb in order for it to compile on Debian.  Since I would like to continue using Debian stable, does someone know how I can install a more recent version of libusb in Debian so that I can get this program to work?  Am I understanding the problem properly or is there another issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could download the [source code of `libusb`](https://git.libusb.org/libusb.git) , compile it, and install it (e.g. in `/usr/local/`), then compile your `ipad_charge.c` with

```
  gcc -Wall -Wextra -O -g -v -H -I/usr/local/include/ -L /usr/local/lib \
       ipad_charge.c -lusb-1.0 -o ipad_charge
```

be sure that `-H` tells you that the right include files (in `/usr/local/`) are used, and that `-v` (or even maybe `-Wl,-v`) tells you that the right libraries (in `/usr/local/`) are used.

Comment: Hi Basile - the instructions for installation are to run sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev
git clone https://github.com/mkorenkov/ipad_charge.git
cd ipad_charge/
make
sudo make install so the actual compiling happens after running make.  How do I tell gcc to use the correct include files?

Comment: Hi Basile - thank you for replying.  I'm not used to downloading source and compiling, so thank you for explaining.  I understand now that I need to edit the gcc compile statement in makefile to refer to /usr/local/lib, but when I use your statement it does not work.  Did you mean to put a backslash after "/usr/local/lib" above?

Comment: The terminating backslash makes the two physical lines a single command line. Obviously, you need to first become familiar with the command line. Did you install Linux on your laptop?

Comment: Thanks for the help, Basile.  This was not a compiling issue, it appears that I needed a more recent libusb.  Everything works now.